# Thana (Dua Isteftah) is necessary on missing Rakah or not?

Tags: salat, fiqh, dua

Asalamualikum sir,
I want to ask you that if I say missing Rakah then SANA is necessary or not for 1st RAKAH, please give me a satisfactory answer.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by SANA?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your querry right!

The dua' al-Istiftah is more likely to be a sunnah and if you joined a congregation prayer in a "position" other than standing you are not asked to perform it. And if you joined the prayer while the congregeation is standing you are only asked to do this dua' if you are sure that you can recite al-fatiha as this is considered as farz (mandatory) by most scholars. For those sects who don't consider the recitation behind the Imam as farz you may be allowed to recite the dua'. But i couldn't find a reference for it being performed once you re-do the missed 1st Rak'ah, maybe this can be explained by this: This dua' should be done at the beginning of the prayer whenever that might be!

Some scholars say if you are used to recite this dua' and missed it and later recall that you have missed it then you may (mustahab) perform sujud sahw for it this is regarded as preferable but not mandatory as this dua' is neither obligatory nor among those sunnah parts of the prayer which may need performing sujud a sahw to "correct" your prayer.

References:

[This](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/106404) is one of my sources (In Arabic) and an [other](https://islamqa.info/en/135290) in english

Answer (score 0):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions.

> نْ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم إِذَا
>   افْتَتَحَ الصَّلاَةَ قَالَ ‏ "‏ **سُبْحَانَكَ اللَّهُمَّ وَبِحَمْدِكَ**
>   **وَتَبَارَكَ اسْمُكَ وَتَعَالَى جَدُّكَ وَلاَ إِلَهَ غَيْرُكَ** ‏"
>
> Aishah narrated: "When the Prophet opened the Salat he would say:
>   (Subhanaka Allahumma wa bihamdika wa tabarakasmuka, wa ta'ala jadduka
>   wa la ilaha ghairuk)" 'Glorious You are O Allah, and with Your praise,
>   and blessed is Your Name, and exalted is Your majesty, and none has
>   the right to be worshipped but You.'([Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/95))

It would be good if you more eloborate your question,However if you have missed the 1st rakah with Imam in prayers then you have to start with Thana or dua Isteftah ,which is regarded as the Sunnah part of the prayer.

Also see [this](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/07/30/a-latecomers-prayer-when-is-one-considered-to-have-missed-a-cycle-rakat/).

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: I'm not sure but to me it seems that OP wants to know whether he needs to recite this dua' when he is performing his missed 1st raka'.