# Salat started later

Tags: salat, reference-request

I was there in mosque when Iqamat was being given. But intentionally I stared after sometime when salat was started as I have make my dress wel prepared for salat. Then I joined. It was still salat going on in 1st rakaat and Ruku was not made still started reciting sana then told Aa'udhubillah then Bismillahi rrahmaaani rrahiiim as soon as I tell it the imam goes for ruku. So I can't start Sura Fatiha. Will my salat be valid as I go for ruku without reciting at least one verse from the holy Al Qur'an though reciting at least one verse from Al Qur'an is farz?
 Please answer my question by mentioning ayats of Al Qur'an and sayings of Prophet (sm) as I don't know whether to repeat the Salat or not

Answer (score 1):

First you shouldn't waste time once the call for prayer has been made. And if you had the time to recite al-Fatiha before the Imam stands up from ruku' you should do so!

Second if your prayer is invalid so how about a person who reaches the lines once the Imam moved to ruku'? 
Of course al-fatiha is considered as fard but not for all madhabs. On the other hand to recite al-fatiha fully you must join the prayer while the Imam is standing not right before he moves to ruku'.
Yes we have the hadith saying:

> "Whoever does not recite Al-Fatiha in his prayer, his prayer is invalid." (See for example in sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/150))

But this hadith doesn't explicitly say in each rak'a!
And of course hadiths such as this from sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/433) support the view of reciting it, even if hanafi scholars say it is not necessary for a follower to recite behind the Imam.

But we on the other hand have a hadith which clearly say if we join a congregation and could perform at least one ruku' in a complete manner the rak'a counts fully so we are not asked to add this rak'a to what we may have missed before (including the recitation of al-fatiha).
See for example in sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/205) and sahih [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/206), while this version from sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/503) is more explicitly explaining the matter:

> when you come to pray while we are prostrating ourselves, you must prostrate yourselves, and do not reckon it anything (rak’ah) and who finds a rak'ah, he in fact finds the prayer.

Please note that the translation of this hadith is not correct so may quote is a corrected version of the linked hadith!

From this -technical- perspective of course your prayer is valid but you missed to gain thawab (rewards) for reciting al-fatiha due to a possibly waste of time. As you should have been in the line of the congregation once the Imam starts the prayer as you apparently where at the mosque!

> ... as I don't know whether to repeat the Salat or not

of course you are free to repeat it, note that even a minority of scholars consider not reading al-fatiha a reason for repeating a prayer or adding a raka'a even if the above evidences are stronger and show that it is not necessary, if one missed the qiyam!

Read also this fatwa in [English](https://islamqa.info/en/74999).

Comment: But I could read at least one verse of Sura Al Fatiha instead of reading Sana which is sunnat.As it was first rakat I started from Sana.Was I correct?

Comment: I started later due to a problem.But I could read at least one verse if sura Fatiha instead of reading Sana.please make it clear

Comment: @MdShantoIslam what should I make clear? The hadith says if you could perform ruku' than you have performed the whole rak'ah (so this includes the recitation of al-Fatiha) it is best to complete reciting al-fatiha but it is not necessary if you fear that the imam may move from ruk'u to standing while you are still reciting. As you've certainly recited al-Fatiha in the following rak'a you have fulfilled the fard!

Comment: I haven't receited Sura Fatiha I started Sana then Aa'ujubillah then Bismillah...but by this tie the call for the ruku was given.was I correct beginning from Sana instead of beginning from Sura Fatiha?

Comment: @MdShantoIslam again: What do you want? I mean you asked is my prayer valid the answer is yes! I even posted a hadith saying why! But for the future you should in such cases overthink whether reciting dua' al-Istiftiah is more important than reciting al-fatiha and if you know the Imam you may yourself decide whether to stop the recitiaion and move to ruku' or complete reciting al-fatiha as fast as it would be allowed. Not reciting al-fatiha is no problem as you at least need to perform it once as i mentioned in my answer!

Comment: @MdShantoIslam and please I'm not a scholar so consider reading this http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33382/where-and-to-whom-can-i-ask-for-answers-to-my-questions-and-doubts and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32793/catch-up-with-rapid-recitation-in-taraweeh-skip-sana http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30493/thana-dua-isteftah-is-necessary-on-missing-rakah-or-not

Comment: The fatwa you posted clearly answers the question too!