# Does reciting dua Sana in the beginning of Salah invalidate Salah according to Shiism?

Tags: salat, fiqh, shiism

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

**Does reciting dua Sana in the beginning of Salah invalidate Salah, according to Shiism?**

Dua Sana, Sunnis recite after Takbeeratul Ehram:

[image]

***Please, give the evidence from Shia sources, or Sunni sources!***

Comment: May we know the context behind your question?

Comment: What kind of context do you want? Do you mean the question is not clear?

Comment: @Ahmed, I am studying Shiism. According to Shiism many things we Sunnis do are wrong.

Comment: @Ahmed, It is the matter of Jannah and Jahannam.

Comment: From Sunni perspective this is not a question of Jannah (obligatory) or Jahannam (forbidden) it is a question of following a sunnah or recomendation or not. At least in the Maliki madhhab performing this du'a is not mentioned. Further the wording of a specific du'a itself is not agreed upon between madhhabs (see for example the different wordings and du'as which are used [here in Arabic Wikipedia](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%AD&oldid=56139997)), the third is partly used by shi'a.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Do our Shia brothers recite this du'a?

Comment: See also [Is it proven to say this du'a before niyyah of salah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48703/is-it-proven-to-say-this-dua-before-niyyah-of-salah), [Catch up with rapid recitation in taraweeh skip sana](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32793/catch-up-with-rapid-recitation-in-taraweeh-skip-sana), [Thana du'a isteftah is necessary on missing rak'ah or not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30493/thana-dua-isteftah-is-necessary-on-missing-rakah-or-not) and [Istiftah shi'a view](https://ar.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%AD)